Accidentlally messed up yarn (Invariant Violation: Expected a key)
I accidentaly typed following command in yarn
yarn config set ""
And now anything I type using yarn I get following error:
Invariant Violation: Expected a key
    at invariant (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:2318:15)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:63549:55)
    at parse (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:63696:21)
    at module.exports.exports.default (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:63258:96)
    at loadRcFile (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:56992:58)
    at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:56966:14
    at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:97395:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseRcPaths (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:97393:78)
    at Object.findRc (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:97407:10)

I tried re installing yarn but it did not help.
I think I messed up the configuration file, but can't find a way to reset it.
Can someone help?
